# Many games stuttery - nvidia

Tags: nvidia, xorg, games, performance

Many games I play are stuttery, (run at a fine fps, but pause randomly every second or so). This happens both when running a native game such as Amnesia, and a game through wine like LoL or WoW. Occasionally I can stop Amnesia from doing it by restarting it and turning SSAO on and off repeatedly, which is a bit weird. I am using the proprietary Nvidia drivers (nvidia-current, the beta ones aren't compatible with my card). Here is the output from `lshw -c video`

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: d
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:22 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:fbec0000-fbedffff
```

How do I fix this issue, or is my GPU just not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete guess, but in my experience the symptoms you describe may have nothing to do with your video card. I'm referring to your description that the frame-rate is cool, and then suddenly things stutter.

To be on the safe side, use system monitor or something similar just to check if your not peaking out your resources (cpu, memory, disk).

I'm not saying it's not your video card, but just make sure everything else is fine.

Apologies for not being able to give better advice.

Comment: I am indeed peaking out on cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Try install e17 and login into that when playing games.  Unity takes a lot more resources.

When logging into e17 (Enlightenment), turn off all the compositing and effects as you go through the wizard.

I did this on my Macbook mid 2010 and was getting 30FPS using Unity dropping to 20 at times but get 50-60 using e17 in TF2